# libfaketime, the file /etc/faketimerc doesn't change the ouput of the date command

Tags: docker, ntp

I am using the librarie "[libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime)" to fake the time of my system. My objective is to change the time inside a docker container, independently of the host time. It can allow me to transform the container as a ntp server, distributing the fake time to the host. (I know I shouldn't sync a ntp server to itself, and i shouldn't peer to a server giving fake time but it is for testing purposes).

By looking at the [readme](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime#readme), i found the possibility to change the date and time system-wide, faking directly the output of the date command.

It is using environment variables and the file `/etc/faketimerc`. The file is allowing the time modification wanted. [Details on the exact configuration.](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime/issues/240)

I replicated the configuration of the [link above](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime/issues/240), I have all 3 environment variables and the file configured. But I cant change the output of the date command.

[image]

The librarie is working when I use basic modification like : faketime -f ‘-10d’ date` (echo the fake time to the terminal).

**Edit :** For information, libfaketime doesn't change the time distributed by the server  (running ntpd). So the client is not stepping to the fake time displayed by the date command.

Comment: Your screenshot shows a typo in the first line. That's also why it's never a good idea to use screenshots of text: not so visible.

Comment: You were right, not only i needed to change the name of the variable, the path  was also wrong. Thanks